# React Native State not update

Tags: react-native

my app need to internet for fetch database.
when WIFI is on and open app everything is good and after show logo for some second navigate to main page, but when my WIFI is off and open app undoubted can't fetch data but when turn on my WIFI data not fetching, it mean the state that save data not update with connect to internet, should close app open again for fetching...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Animated, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import { Spinner } from 'native-base';
import Network from './Network'
const SuperUrl = 'http://site.domain'

export default class Intro extends Component {
constructor(){
super();
this.state={
  isLoading: true,
  dataSource: null,
}
}

componentDidMount()
{
return fetch(SuperUrl+'/check')
.then((response)=> response.json())
.then((responseJson)=>this.setState({
  isLoading:false,
  dataSource: responseJson.app_update
}));
}

render() {
var appStatus = this.state.dataSource;
if(this.state.isLoading===false && appStatus===0)
{
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.props.navigation.replace('test')
  }, 2500);
}

return (
<View>...Logo Content...</View>
<Network />
 )    

}

}
```

and my component that check internet connect is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NetInfo, View } from 'react-native'
import {Root, Toast} from 'native-base'

export default class Network extends Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={connection: null}
}
componentWillMount(){
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange',this.handleconnectionChange);
}
componentWillUnmount(){
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange',this.handleconnectionChange);
  }
  handleconnectionChange= (isConnected) => {this.setState({connection:isConnected})}
  render() {
return (
  <View style={{flex:1,}}>


    <Root>
    {(this.state.connection!=null && this.state.connection==false)?              
            Toast.show({
            text: "at first please connect to internet.",
            duration: 0,
            type: 'danger'
            })
          :
          null
    }
    </Root>

    <Root>
    {(this.state.connection!=null && this.state.connection==true)?              
            Toast.hide()
          :
          null
    }
    </Root>


  </View>
)
```

}
}

Comment: This might help you to get started https://github.com/rgommezz/react-native-offline

Comment: maybe you can hold a variable that firstly checks the internet connection with [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo)  then updates the state w.r.t this.

Comment: @VilleKoo i have a component that check Internet access

Answer (score 1):

**First ,**
Install this npm package
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-offline][1]
It will provide two components,
1) NetworkProvider
2) NetworkConsumer

**Then ,**
Wrap your entire app inside NetworkProvider as follows

```
<NetworkProvider>
 <App />
</NetworkProvider>
```

**And Finally ,**
You can wrap the child component inside the NetworkConsumer as follows,

```
<NetworkConsumer>
  {({ isConnected }) => (
    isConnected ? (
      <Button title="Download image" onPress={downloadImage} />
    ) : (
      <Text>Downloading images is disabled since you are offline</Text>
    )
  )}
</NetworkConsumer>
```

Hope this works... ;-)

Comment: i have a component that check Internet access

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. It might be useful to note that you don't necessarily need to wrap your entire app inside `NetworkProvider`. You can simply use `NetworkProvider` within a specific screen [as per the example in the repo](https://github.com/rgommezz/react-native-offline/blob/master/example/screens/ComponentsScreen.js)

Comment: Yeah... Thanks for your suggestion @Marklar

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to monitor the status of the Network. This can be done using the [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo).

Next you may have to send the request again when you connect to the network.

Comment: i have a component that check Internet access